# How to select Specific Columns from same row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Here is my table `funcionario`:

```
ID_funcionario  nome    numero  sexo    morada    email     data_nasc
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1              marcio   1234    male    jardim    marcio    11/23/2017
2              joel     3333    male   bemfica     ragy     11/25/2017
```

I want to select specifically only the nome "marcio" and number 1234.

For example, it should appear like this:

```
nome    numero  
----------------
marcio  1234
```

This is what I tried:

```
select * 
from funcionario 
where nome = 'marcio' and numero = '1234';
```

but that just shows me the whole row like this:

```
ID_funcionario  nome    numero  sexo    morada    email     data_nasc
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1              marcio   1234    male    jardim    marcio    11/23/2017
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `select * ...`, **all** the columns of the table are returned.

If you want to get only some columns, then you must be more specific, like this:

```
select nome, numero 
from funcionario 
where nome = 'marcio' and numero = '1234';
```

Comment: You are welcome! If it helped, please select this as an answer (the checkmark bellow the answer) :)

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting every column by this: 
`SELECT * FROM ...`

try to select the columns you need by:

`select nome, numero from funcionario where nome ='marcio'and numero='1234';`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers above, you could also write it this way:

```
select nome, numero 
from funcionario 
where nome = 'marcio'
```

It will return your desired result as well.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM [TABLENAME] WHERE Col1 = ''`

or

`SELECT T_Col1, T_Col2 FROM [TABLENAME] WHERE T_Col1 = ''`